# I'm using ytdl-core for a music bot, and it keeps outputting that play is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am using ytdl-core and node-opus to add music functionality to my bot. I am also following a tutorial. Up until I started to add queuing functionality, the bot worked fine. As I integrated the queuing, the bot could still join and leave voice channels, but can't play music. It outputs `(node:22116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: play is not defined`

As per comments on the video, I have tried switching `play` to `playstream`. This worked originally, but doesn't help, only outputting that it is not defined.

Here is the command:

```
      if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You must be connected to a voice channel.");
      if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You must supply a __valid__ URL.");
      let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0]);
      if (!validate) return message.channel.send("You must supply a __valid__ URL.");
      let info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
      let data = active.get(message.guild.id) || {};
      if (!data.connection) data.connection = await message.member.voiceChannel.join();
      if (!data.queue) data.queue = [];
      data.guildID = message.guild.id; 
      data.queue.push ({
        songTitle: info.title,
        requester: message.author.tag,
        url: args[0],
        announceChannel: message.channel.id
      });
      if (!data.dispatcher) play();
      else {
        message.channel.send(`Added song to queue: ${info.title} || Requested by: ${message.author.id}`);
        active.set(message.guild.id, data);
```

I'd like to be able to still follow the tutorial to fully integrate the queuing.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the `play()` function in previous code, so you also can't use it.

Here is an **example** of how your `play()` function **could look**:

```
const queue = msg.client.queue;
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

async function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = await queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        await serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        await queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const stream = await ytdl(song.url, {
        filter: 'audioonly'
    });
    const dispatcher = await serverQueue.connection.playStream(stream)
        .on('end', async reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.');
            serverQueue.songs.shift('Stream is not generating quickly enough');
            await play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
}
```

**My queue is constructed as following:**

```
const queueConstruct = {
                    textChannel: msg.channel,
                    voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: [],
                    volume: 2,
                    playing: true
                };
```

**It could be that you have to change some lines of code, so that it works for your bot!**